# Telegram Bot privacy mode enabled but the BOT still reads all the messages in the group

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, telegram-bot

Possibly if there is any workaround to keep bot as admin at the same time?

I have my Bot with Privacy Mode Enabled. I wanted it to read messages starting with `/`.

[image]

[image]

This is from Telegram Documentation. It will still reply to messages which neither start with / or have username of bot in it.

**MY CODE:**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express'
import * as cors from 'cors'

const bot = express()

bot.use(cors({ origin: true}))

bot.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    const telegramText = req.body
    && req.body.message
    && req.body.message.chat
    && req.body.message.chat.id
    && req.body.message.from
    && req.body.message.from.first_name

    if (telegramText) {
        const chat_id = req.body.message.chat.id
        const first_name = req.body.message.from.first_name
        const receivedMessage = req.body.message.text
      if (typeof userInput !== 'undefined') {

        return res.status(200).send({
            method: 'sendMessage',
            chat_id,
            text: `Here\'s your reply`
        })
    }
    }
    return res.status(200).send({status: 'An error occurred'})

})

export const router = functions.https.onRequest(bot)
```

[image]

See it is replying all the messages.

Though I don't want to verify it here if the message is starting with `/` or not. It will just consume my Firebase Cloud Functions Invocations. Why is the bot reading all messages?

I just don't want my Cloud Function to get triggered on each message so I want to prevent the bot to read all messages.

**EDIT:** I've tried:

(1) Waiting for a while

(2) Deleting and creating another bot.

**(3) Removing Bot as Admin does help but then my bot won't be able to do most of the tasks.**

Comment: Seems information from docs you refer to is related to groups. In my understanding, if it is private chat, or channel (item 4 form docs) bot will receive all messages.

Comment: @Nymphetamine I'm using it in a GROUP. See that bot is an ADMIN

Comment: ok, I'm just trying to help you.
Had some time passed after privacy mode was enabled? Maybe it didn't applied when you tested.

Comment: @Nymphetamine any solution??

Comment: @Nymphetamine I waited for more than an hour. I also tried creating new bot.

Comment: Privacy mode is enabled by default for all bots, except bots that were added to the group as admins (bot admins always receive all messages). (https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode)

Comment: @Nymphetamine then how do I allow bot to send message without making admin? Though I want to be admin so it can ban users.

Comment: It could be two bots with different roles.

Comment: @Nymphetamine removing bot from admin did resolve the issue. Still finding a workaround if can do it while keeping admin

Answer (score 0):

Question is old, but I'm answering to help anyone who reads later:

#### Answer:

According to [official doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode):

> **Privacy mode is enabled by default for all bots, except bots that were
> added to the group as admins (bot admins always receive all messages).**

#### Possible alternative way:

So, **seems there is no solution for this yet**; but in case you writing a group manager bot or some sort of **bots those need to have admin rights but no need to read messages directly** (another bot can reads message and call this bot via it's script's URL to do something on specific message) **and also load off the server**, you may consider **`allowed_updates`** field of [**`setWebhook`**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) method:

> **A JSON-serialized list of the update types you want your bot to
> receive. For example, specify `[“message”, “edited_channel_post”, “callback_query”]` to only receive updates of these types. See Update
> for a complete list of available update types. Specify an empty list
> to receive all update types except chat_member (default). If not
> specified, the previous setting will be used. Please note that this
> parameter doesn't affect updates created before the call to the
> setWebhook, so unwanted updates may be received for a short period of
> time.**

Comment: " (another bot can reads message and call this bot" -> That sounds to me like having 2 different bots.

Comment: @Dharmaraj true, just 2 different script! no extra charge. (it's only helpful if you wanna some kind of load balancing)...

Comment: The problem is this bot is meant for public use so it won't be ideal if we ask everyone to add 2 bots.